# How to get the speaker activity level in Adobe Air app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Our Air application that runs on both iOS and Android needs to be able to check the speaker activity levels (actual output volume at a certain moment).

I have tried using the following to fill a ByteArray and check values with no luck.

```
SoundMixer.computeSpectrum
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get your desired info from using this framework:

http://www.everyday3d.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/26/classic-sound-equalizer-in-flashas3/

You can also look into the source of this library and see how they monitor the sound channel output if you want to make your own tool.

Comment: That framework users SoundMixer.computeSpectrum. Either that doesn't work in Air or there is a problem with my application.

Comment: Why not try to add the framework to a test app and see if it works? If it does - the problem is within your code and you can fix it looking at the source of the framework as an example. If it doesn't, you might want to look into upgrading your SDK with the latest version (worked great for me in 3.8 and 3.9)